Why does apt / apt-get reccomend packages that are missing?
Occasionally, apt / apt-get recommends extra packages:
# sudo apt-get install zangband angband moria endless-sky
[...]
The following additional packages will be installed:
  angband-data endless-sky-data zangband-data
Suggested packages:
  angband-audio angband-bigtiles
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  angband angband-data endless-sky endless-sky-data moria zangband zangband-data

But trying to install them most-often fails:
# sudo apt-get install angband-audio angband-bigtiles
[...]
Package angband-audio is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package angband-bigtiles is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'angband-audio' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'angband-bigtiles' has no installation candidate

What's going on here?

As Debian packages can both recommend and suggest other packages, with different meaning and defaults, you should take care not to mix those two terms. Here the packages are just suggested, not recommended.

After apt update?

@PersianGulf - yes, after update.

It you're root (as implied by the # prompt) you don't need sudo

In some cases, these packages are in repositories (more accurately, archive areas) that aren’t enabled on your system. That’s the gist of what’s happening with angband-audio: while angband itself is in main, and therefore available to install in all Debian setups, angband-audio is in non-free, and therefore only available if non-free is enabled. As an additional twist, angband-audio was buggy and wasn’t included in the last few releases of Debian. That’s now been fixed in Debian testing and unstable, but unless you’re running testing or unstable with non-free enabled, or have those repositories enabled, you won’t be able to install it. (In Debian 12, that’s really a bug in angband; but it doesn’t break anything so it’s unlikely to be fixed there. It will be fixed in Debian 13.)
In other cases, it’s just a bug — typically, an old package that no longer exists, or never existed. That’s what’s happening with angband-bigtiles; it seems it was never available in Debian. Perhaps the angband maintainer at the time intended to package it, and never got round to it.
Given that Debian releases are supposed to be consistent, that is to say, that each package in a given Debian release can only rely on other packages in the same Debian release, curious readers may wonder how this can happen at all. Surely there’s some automation to check that packages mentioned in the various kinds of dependencies are actually available? There is, but only for non-alternative dependencies and recommendations; packages are allowed to suggest other packages that don’t exist.

If you had installed those packages in a different environment/distribution, where angband-audio and angband-bigtiles were available, they would have been used. They're unavailable in your current repositories.
Check the angband information, which may tell you what to do. Start with dpkg -L angband.
